# ¿Es válido usar "le" en el ejemplo "Será mejor que le ayudes [a ella]"?

Tags: laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

Quisiera saber si es válido decir:

> Será mejor que **le** ayudes

cuando se hace referencia a una mujer (es decir, ir a ayudar a una mujer), o que si necesariamente tiene que ser:

> Será mejor que **la** ayudes

En [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo) encontré algunos ejemplos:

> Le pedí disculpas a mi madre.
>
> Le dije a su hermana que viniera.

Pero no me queda claro.

Comment: *le* actúa como el objeto de la acción. Cuando se muestra el sujeto, es posible dispensarlo: *le pedí disculpas* (= a mi madre), aquí queda implicado a quién nos estamos refiriendo. En este caso *le* actúa como objeto del sujeto sustituido *mi madre*. Esto aplica más cuando se tiene el debido contexto, pues decir *le dije que viniera* queda como una afirmación vacía si no queda claro a quién nos estamos refiriendo. Lo mismo ocurre con *será mejor que le ayudes* (= a él o a ella).

Comment: En los ejemplos que das no hay leísmo porque el *le* es un objeto indirecto, que siempre se expresa con *le*. Los objetos directos son *disculpas* y *que viniera*. En el ejemplo que das (*Será mejor que le ayudes*), el *le* es el objeto directo, por lo que sí hay leísmo. El leísmo está aceptado para referentes masculinos, pero no para femeninos. La única frase correcta si el referente es femenino es *Será mejor que **la** ayudes.*

Comment: @Yay el léismo está aceptado en la lengua culta con referentes femeninos cuando se trata del de cortesía, pero estrictamente hablando, *dentro* del sistema leísta, usando *le/s* para cualquier objeto directo sería aceptable, sea tal uso también aceptable o no en la lengua culta.

Comment: @guifa Me temo que no entiendo tu comentario. ¿A qué te refieres con el uso de cortesía? Y, por otro lado, no entiendo eso del uso correcto *dentro del sistema leísta*. Me suena a decir que horrores como *la dije que viniera* o *si quieres ese libro, cógele* son válidos dentro de un sistema laísta/leísta como el habitual entre muchos hablantes de Castilla. Si acaso, son coherentes, pero ese sistema no es válido en español.

Comment: Es válido de las dos formas. Para el caso de una mujer: "Será mejor que **le** ayudes" y "Será mejor que **la** ayudes". Y para el caso de un hombre se puede decir también de las dos formas: "Será mejor que **le** ayudes" y "Será mejor que **lo** ayudes"

Comment: @Gorpik el *leísmo de cortesía* es el uso de *le* cuando hace referencia a *usted* (pero empleando *lo/la* cuando refiere a cualquier cosa de la 3.ª persona). Estos hablantes preguntarán a una señora de edad *¿Cómo **le** puedo ayudar?* a la vez que preguntarán a esa señora sobre su hija, ¿cómo **la** puedo ayudar?*.  Tal uso de *le*, con referencia femenina, se admite en la lengua culta de la misma forma que el leísmo para animados masculinos singulares (*al hombre le vi*, pero *el libro lo vi* y *los hombres los vi*) se acepta en la culta.

Comment: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=le%C3%ADsmo §4.g: Otro caso de leísmo generalizado en todo el mundo hispánico es el llamado «leísmo de cortesía». Se trata del uso de *le(s)* en función de complemento directo cuando el referente es un interlocutor al que se trata de *usted*. […] Aunque el «leísmo de cortesía» no está tan generalizado *cuando el interlocutor es femenino*, **debe considerarse aceptable**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay una diferencia importante entre los ejemplos que sacas de la RAE y tu caso: la función sintáctica del pronombre. El pronombre *le* puede usarse como objeto indirecto (OI) en ambos géneros y también en algunos casos como objeto directo (OD) en el género masculino. En los ejemplos de la RAE funciona como objeto indirecto (OI):

> Le pedí disculpas a mi madre --> OD es *disculpas*; OI es *a mi madre*, duplicado en *le*
>
> Le dije a su hermana que viniera --> OD es *que viniera*; OI es *a mi hermana*, duplicado en *le*

En cambio, en el caso que propones, el pronombre es OD; en ese caso, al ser femenino, solo podemos usar *la*:

> Será mejor que *la* ayudes.

**Uso de los pronombres *la*, *lo* y *le* (o sus correspondientes plurales).**

El castellano, como las demás lenguas romances, ha perdido la declinación de los sustantivos y adjetivos que sí se da en latín. Sin embargo, se mantienen restos de estas declinaciones en los pronombres. Según su función gramatical usamos distintas formas (casos) de estos.

El uso de los distintos pronombres personales en castellano no ofrece especiales dificultades a la mayoría de los hablantes, con una notable excepción: la confusión de los pronombres *lo*, *la* y *le*, con sus respectivos plurales.

Los pronombres *lo*, *la* deben usarse para la tercera persona cuando su función sintáctica es la de objeto directo (caso acusativo); *lo* en masculino y *la* en femenino:

> Cogí el libro. --> Lo cogí.
>
> Escribí la carta. --> La escribí.

Por contra, el pronombre *le* se usa cuando la función sintáctica es la de objeto indirecto (caso dativo), independientemente del género:

> Di el libro a Andrés. --> Le di el libro.
>
> Escribí una carta a María. --> Le escribí una carta.

Hay un caso que puede inducir a confusión: cuando el objeto directo es una persona concreta, en muchas zonas de España es habitual usar *le* en lugar de *lo* para el género masculino singular, uso que se considera aceptable:

> Acompañé a Marta. --> La acompañé.
>
> Acompañé a Pedro. --> *Le* acompañé. (*Lo acompañé* también es correcto y es el uso principal en el resto del mundo hispanohablante).

En cambio:

> Acompañé a Pedro y su hermano --> *Los* acompañé.

La confusión entre estos tres pronombres da lugar a tres incorrecciones en el habla:

- *Leísmo*: Uso del pronombre *le* en lugar del pronombre *lo* y, en menor medida, del pronombre *la*.
- *Laísmo*: Uso del pronombre *la* en lugar del pronombre *le*.
- *Loísmo*: Uso del pronombre *lo* en lugar del pronombre *le*.

Estas incorrecciones se dan, principalmente, en zonas de Castilla, si bien el leísmo también es frecuente en otras áreas hispanohablantes en las que el español coexiste con otra lengua cuyo sistema de pronombres no distingue entre el acusativo y el dativo.

De estos tres, el loísmo es el menos habitual:

> Dije a Juan que viniera mañana. --> Lo dije que viniera mañana.

El *laísmo* y el *leísmo*, en cambio, son más habituales:

> Cogí el libro. --> Le cogí.
>
> Escribí una carta a María. --> La escribí una carta.

El loísmo nunca se da aislado, siempre existe un laísmo paralelo. Pero tampoco es raro que laísmo y leísmo se den a la vez en un mismo hablante. En estos casos, el hablante nunca (o casi nunca) utiliza el pronombre *lo*; usa siempre *le* en masculino y *la* en femenino.

Un caso tomado de la realidad. En cierta ocasión leí un cartel junto a unos lavabos:

> El agua es un bien escaso: no le malgastes.

Se podía haber usado *la* (refiriéndose al agua) o *lo* (refiriéndose al bien); sin embargo, quien escribió el cartel fue a elegir justamente el único pronombre incorrecto para este caso.

Otro caso también tomado de la realidad. Una persona miraba con interés un libro que tenía otra, la cual, al verlo, dijo a la primera:

> ¿Le quieres? Pues si le quieres, cógele, léele y, cuando le acabes, me le devuelves.

Cada uno de los seis *le* de esta frase debería ser *lo*. Un caso un tanto extremo, pero real.

En la mayoría de los casos, un hablante cuidadoso no debería tener problemas a la hora de elegir el pronombre correcto: en la mayoría de los casos en que hay objeto indirecto, también lo hay directo, y no suele ser difícil distinguir entre ambos. Sin embargo, las excepciones no son infrecuentes.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Como bonus, y aprovechando que hay una recompensa en juego, ¿te animas a hacer una explicación general del leísmo/laísmo que pueda servir como canónica?

Comment: @fedorqui De acuerdo, voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Pues la has clavado. ¡Qué gran respuesta! Muchísimas gracias por ella, seguro que será útil para mucha gente en el futuro.

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias :) De todos modos, le falta algo de ayuda para distinguir entre objeto directo e indirecto, pero no sabía cómo escribirla de una forma sencilla.