# Indirect object pronouns for persons

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos

I've always been a bit confused about when to use the indirect object pronoun `le` for persons. Specifically, is it necessary (or even forbidden) when specifying the person. e.g. `Voy a visitarle a Pedro.`

I've also seen `lo` and `la` (the direct object pronouns) used in place of `le`, for persons, and quite frequently so. What's up with this? Is it strictly correct? The only situation in which I can imagine this would be right is with the verb `tener`.

Comment: Interesting to read: [leísmo, laísmo, loísmo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17727/1674)

Comment: Le / La / Lo  is one of the most complicated subjects you could read about in spanish. Everybody does it wrong depending on the country and the part of the country you are in. I suggest you read that article.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea it was such a tricky subject. Suppose I'll read the article and try to follow the RAE standard!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cómo usar el leísmo en el ejemplo "Será mejor que le ayudes \[a ella\]"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-le%c3%adsmo-en-el-ejemplo-ser%c3%a1-mejor-que-le-ayudes-a-ella)

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with the duplicate, but I'm not sure if he's confused about when to use le/lo/la or when reduplication of the (in)direct pronoun is necessary. HOpefully he can clarify

Comment: @guifa: Both, in fairness! The former is perhaps the more thorny issue however.

Comment: Agreed with @guifa. So Noldorin, could you [edit] your post to clarify what your full question is, based on your reading of the other one I linked? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but to give you some examples of how NOT to use this.
LO is generic for objects. LE is always for masculine. The problem starts with femenine, because LA and LE is hard to distinguish:

Decirla algo (a ella): Never use "LA" for femenine indirect objects. Correct is generic for persons: DecirLE

But most of the times, you hear:  Peinarla (a ella), which sounds completely perfect. And it shouldn't be right, but you hear it everywhere.

Voy al parque a cogerle = Always means a person, but some people use this for objects, which is wrong. Should be LO for objects.